# How to implement 2 different grid structures in one section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grid

I am trying to mimic the header-graphic navigation from this site:
http://wpengine.com/

It seems that they are not applying any grid on the header-graphic area, but having them separated as 2 divs. In their Hero block (container) area. I am looking to recreate the giant content area (fluid content box with 5 navigation buttons). Please try to stretch the right side of browser, the main navigation boxes stays at the same position and the left area (content) extend its as fluid. I am trying to create that appearance.

These are the codes below are the code I inspected from google developer tool:

```
/* For content navigation area */
.gwc_slide_buttons {
  width: 375px;
  height: 556px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

/* For content area */
.gwc_slider {
  left: 0;
  right: 375px;
  height: 556px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

What I have in my code:

```
/* For content area */
.slider_content {
  position: absolute; 
}

/* For the content navigation area */
.slider_content_navi {
  width: 430px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

As you can see here, I tried both absolute positioning for my content and navigation button, but it is not working as it should be compare to the code I have inspected.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Here is the preview on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lee61013/CeLDk/2/).

Comment: Is it possible that you have a mistake on line 2 - `gwc_slide_buttons` should be `.gwc_slide_buttons`?

Comment: oops, I was meant to type as .gwc_slide_buttons, not without "."

Comment: Actually, I am asking how would you recreate the giant header-graphics area (content with 5 navigation boxes). Please try to stretch the right side of browser, the main navigation boxes stays at the same position and the left area (content) extend its as fluid. I am trying to create that appearance.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved through [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) aka different design for different screen sizes. Your *HTML* will stay the same but you can apply absolutely different styles for different screen sizes.

Also I noticed that you are using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). Check it's [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and the [Responsive Design](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support) support.